# How to get Amazon MWS Reports Java client library to download specific Document version

Tags: java, amazon-mws

I have some code that processes Amazon Settlement Reports (XML format). Up until now the user would download the XML file from Amazon Seller Central and load it into the application for processing.

I have added some code which will use the MWS Reports API , via the Amazon Java client library, to search for available settlement reports and allow the user to select the one they want, fetch it and process it. This all works fine except that the Refunds are not processed.

In comparing the XML retrieved by the different methods I find that the downloaded files are a newer format than those from the API.

`<DocumentVersion>'4.01'</DocumentVersion>`

Versus:

`<DocumentVersion>'3.01'</DocumentVersion>`

In the older version the `<Refund>` element is called `<Adjustment>` but the XML is otherwise the same.

As I attempted to find an answer to this I came across an MWS forum post dated 11 Aug 2014:

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/ann.jspa?annID=186

This announces the changes to the settlement reports and "notes" that the client libraries are not changing.

The latest version of the Reports API Java Client was released on 30 Sep 2014 (i.e. after the announcement) but that is the one that I am using, so does not seem to use the new document version.

Can anyone suggest how I may tell the client library which version to use?

P.S. Another issue is the latest reports are missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another announcement that I missed earlier:

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/ann.jspa?annID=240

This is the real issue here and it explains why reports since the end of May are missing.

The important part is:

> The enumeration value for the XML Settlement Report is changing from _GET_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_ to _GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_XML_.

So when setting up the report list request you need to change the report type as shown below:

```
    GetReportListRequest req = new GetReportListRequest();

    ArrayList<String> typeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    typeArrayList.add("_GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_XML_");

    TypeList typeList = new TypeList();
    typeList.setType(typeArrayList);

    req.setReportTypeList(typeList);
```

Once this is done the newer reports can be found and the XML for the adjustments and refunds are found.